# Flot: Plot rolling 1 hour chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have this code to plot a chart which is invoked at a 5 second interval. How can I set the X axis to plot for a rolling 1 hour period?

```
/**
 * Plot chart from retrieved quote data.
*/
function plotData() {
for(var i = 0; i < Quotes.length; ++i) {
    if(dataSets[i].length == 7) dataSets[i].shift();
    var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    dataSets[i].push([timestamp, Quotes[i].unitprice]);
}
var data = [];
for(var i = 0; i < Quotes.length; ++i) {
    data.push({label: Quotes[i].stock, data: dataSets[i]});
}

$.plot('#livetrades-chart', data, 
{ xaxis: { axisLabel: 'Time',  axisLabelUseCanvas: true, 
  mode: 'time', timeformat: '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S', timezone: TIME_ZONE },
  yaxis: { axisLabel: 'Stock Price', axisLabelUseCanvas: true, tickDecimals: 2 } 
});
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: So if the length is 7, you `shift` off the first point. Shouldn't that be `(3600 seconds in hour / 5 second interval) = 720 points` to give you a "rolling" hour?

Comment: That sounds right. Thank you. But how can I set this ticks? Is it minTick, maxTick?

Comment: How do you want the ticks to look?

Comment: Can you show us a mockup of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as far as DNS suggests your cuestion is how did you setup the flot to updates also the xaxis.

here is a runing plunkr for that scenario. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/TWpWhL?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

The [real-time updates example](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/realtime/index.html) demonstrates rolling data, where each time a new point is added the oldest one is shifted off the array.  What you want to do is basically identical, except with a time axis.

Edit: I still don't understand what the question is; your screenshot shows a time axis, and if you have an hour of data in your array (as opposed to the five seconds shown) then it will show an hour on the axis.

I think maybe you're confused about having to configure the x-axis in some way.  You don't: if you provide data whose x-values are spaced an hour apart, the axis will fit to match it.  The only thing you might need to tweak is the timeformat (see the [Time Series](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data) section of the docs for more info) option, if you want the ticks to appear with only H:M:S rather than Y/M/D.

Comment: Thanks, I've manged to do that; but the time axis is my problem - want to have start and end period of 1 hr.

Comment: @SamSaint-Pettersen, if your data arrays only contain 1 hour of data flot will only show 1 hour.  Do you want them formatted in some fashion?

Comment: Like this: X-axis: (1st point) time now ... 1hr (7th point) from time now so, yes the formatting. I know my question wasn't the most clear. I am sorry about that.

Comment: As Mark said, if you have an hour of data, you should see a one-hour range on the x-axis.  How is what you're seeing different from what you want?

Comment: I am adding a new data point at an interval of 5 seconds. I am adding and should be dropping at the 7th point. I want to scale the X-axis for time so that the end point on said axis is 1 hr from the 1st point added to the chart. Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: @SamSaint-Pettersen But what are you actually seeing right now?  Can you provide a screenshot or jsFiddle?

Comment: [This is the chart that I have.](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/202/t1sw.png/) I know I am being a little dense here, I apologise. What I want is basically something like the rolling chart example from the Flot website, but with those price and time series on. If I could have 1 hour from the initial point that would be good. The initial point being dropped as it reaches the 7th or 8th point...

Comment: Maybe even a 15 or 30 minute interval would be good between points. Problem is setInterval(1800000) means I have to wait 30 mins to see an initial plot; what I want is 5 second interval refresh but a drawn out data series.

Comment: I've updated my answer, but the screenshot doesn't really help clarify what the actual problem is.  You seem to have everything correct already; the only reason it's not showing an hour is because you're generating only five seconds worth of data.